# How to count multiple columns based on conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

dataframe:

```
  a b c d name
0 t t t t john
1 t t t f doe
2 t t f f maria
3 t f f f smith
```

I would like to count the number of true in each column

`df[["a", "b", "c", "d"]].sum()` returns `Series([], dtype: float64)`

I would like to get

```
a b c d
4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sum on boolean columns.

`"t"` and `"f"` are strings not boolean, you have to first convert them to boolean:

```
In [11]: df == "t"
Out[11]:
      a      b      c      d   name
0  True   True   True   True  False
1  True   True   True  False  False
2  True   True  False  False  False
3  True  False  False  False  False

In [12]: (df == "t").sum()
Out[12]:
a       4
b       3
c       2
d       1
name    0
dtype: int64
```

---

on just those columns:

```
In [13]: (df[["a", "b", "c", "d"]] == "t").sum()
Out[13]:
a    4
b    3
c    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```